# How is package-info.java shared between main and test in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, class, package-info

In a maven project, I created a simple Unit test which loads all classes within a given root package, iterates over them and processes some information about their packages (namely whether a specific annotation is provided for a given package).

Given the following files:

```
/src/main/com/andy/Foo.java
/src/main/com/andy/package-info.java
/src/main/com/andy/inner/Bar.java

src/test/com/andy/inner/SomeTest.java
src/test/com/andy/inner/package-info.java
```

when I loaded the `Class<?>` for `Bar.java`, and tried to obtain annotation of its package (using the `Class#getPackage` method), to my surpise I found out that the package somehow shared the annotations from the `src/test` directory, where the `package-info.java` lies next to the `SomeTest.java` file (otherwise the packages are the same).

I have also found out it works the other way around as well, i.e. a class without `package-info.java` in `src/test` seems to share a `package-info.java` from the same package under the `src/main` directory.

Is this specific to a maven project, or is this a regular Java behaviour? Is there a way to not load the related package from the *other* directory?

Comment: If you execute a unit test you have the following on the class path. Production code from `src/main/java/...` and the test code from `src/test/java`... You wrote you have loaded all classes within a given package... that means all classes from the same package which production code + test usually have in common. That's the reason you write usually unit tests which access package private code.

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks for the comment. However, what about the way around? Isn't that strange that declaring a `package-info.java` in `src/test` reflects in the `src/main`? I assume in the unit test, the `src/main` code believes the `package-info` is there because the test code is loaded as well, but what if we run the code in the production, therefore not making the test code available? Would that mean the `package-info` is no longer available for that given class?

Comment: It seemed that you don't see the point: Classpath. The classpath is a combined view of `src/test` and `src/test` ... which exactly reflects the points you are describing. If you have code in `src/main/` which relies on a `package-info` in `src/test´ your code is wrong.. If your code is running in production you have only the `src/main´ on classpath (pluse dependencies none test-scoped) because it's being packaged into a jar file...